# XSL if with tag name

Tags: xml, xslt, compare

I want to compare XML tag name using XSL
Example :

```
<name>
  <item>
     TEST
  </item>
  <out>
     No item
  </out>
</name>
```

Want to know if I'm in `<item>` or not.
In XSL (example, I don't know how to do, but it's the idea) :

```
<xsl:if test="name(.)==item">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />         <!-- it will print "TEST" -->
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="//*">
        <xsl:if test="name(.)='item'">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />         
        </xsl:if>    
    </xsl:for-each>
```